# Привязка приложения к рабочему столу

Tags: python

Как привязать приложение на python к рабочему столу?
есть конечно 'поверх всех окон', но мне нужно именно к рабочему столу, чтобы при использовании команды свернуть все с рабочего стола, приложение осталось.
По сути нужен виджет.

Comment: по теме нагуглил https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273416/how-to-disable-all-resize-possibilities-for-a-window

Comment: Так там же NoResize что соответствует "не изменять размер" ?

Comment: ты ответ смотри: там же понятно все, отлавливаем событие ресайз, устанавливаем this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;